# How can I tokenize a string in R?

Tags: r, tokenize, readability

I am trying to calculate readability, but it seems everything is written to expect either a file path or a Corpus. How do I handle a string?

Error (on the tokenization step):

```
Error: Unable to locate
```

I tried:

```
str<-"Readability zero one.  Ten, Eleven.", "The cat in a dilapidated tophat."
library(koRpus)
ll.tagged <- tokenize(str, lang="en")
readability(ll.tagged,measure="Flesch.Kincaid")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the language file

```
install.koRpus.lang(c("en"))
library(koRpus.lang.en)
ll.tagged <- tokenize(str,  format = "obj", lang = "en")
ll.tagged
   doc_id       token      tag lemma lttr   wclass desc stop stem idx sntc
1    <NA> Readability word.kRp         11     word <NA> <NA> <NA>   1    1
2    <NA>        zero word.kRp          4     word <NA> <NA> <NA>   2    1
3    <NA>         one word.kRp          3     word <NA> <NA> <NA>   3    1
4    <NA>           .     .kRp          1 fullstop <NA> <NA> <NA>   4    1
5    <NA>         Ten word.kRp          3     word <NA> <NA> <NA>   5    2
6    <NA>           ,     ,kRp          1    comma <NA> <NA> <NA>   6    2
                                             [...]                        
10   <NA>         cat word.kRp          3     word <NA> <NA> <NA>  10    3
11   <NA>          in word.kRp          2     word <NA> <NA> <NA>  11    3
12   <NA>           a word.kRp          1     word <NA> <NA> <NA>  12    3
13   <NA> dilapidated word.kRp         11     word <NA> <NA> <NA>  13    3
14   <NA>      tophat word.kRp          6     word <NA> <NA> <NA>  14    3
15   <NA>           .     .kRp          1 fullstop <NA> <NA> <NA>  15    3
```

Comment: I also needed to specify the format="obj" parameter (as you indicated) thanks!